# Node.js - traceroute equivalent

Tags: javascript, node.js, codeship

I have a situation where, for the last 4 months, I've been running deployments via Codeship to MediaTemple Wordpress Managed Hosting for 10 different sites.

Then, out of no where, I started receiving this error for all deployments:

```
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

In troublehsooting, I hit a brick wall from MediaTemple as they want to run a traceroute from Codeship to hit the MediaTemple hosting server before they'll look into anything else.  Only problem is, traceroute is not installed on Codeship.  Neither is MTR.

My deployment is extremely basic.  Runs with GIT over SSH.

```
git config --global user.name "username"
git config --global user.email user@email.com
git remote add production user@server.name:reponame.git
git push production master
```

I'm looking for any way to run a traceroute equivalent via node or Javascript.  I've been a few npm wrappers for traceroute, but if native traceroute is a dependency, that doesn't do me any good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Node script called [sloppy traceroute clone](https://gist.github.com/liamgriffiths/9064335) by Liam Griffiths. I haven't used it myself but it is supposed to do what traceroute does but all in JavaScript.

It needs `raw-socket` and `dns` modules from npm.

Keep in mind that it may still not work on Codeship due to permissions and network configuration.

Comment: I tried something similar called traceroute.js and it choked when getting the raw-socket dependency.

On a side note, if I'm able to run a ping from Codeship to MediaTemple, that should confirm that Codeship can reach the MediaTemple host, right?

And the error that is being reported in an SSH access issue, so traceroute isn't going to yield any pertinent info, correct?